# Windows 10 UWP apps as desktop apps

Tags: uwp, windows-10, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, desktop

Is there a way to package Windows 10 UWP apps as desktop apps with an installer that install and run like a traditional EXE?

I'm interested in utilizing UWP development but do not want to be constrained to the Windows Store model.

Comment: at the time of creating app package You will be asked for x86,x64,ARM. You Can Create X86,x64 package which work on pc and ARM For mobile device if you Tick on both arm x86 x64 your package can be install on 64 bit, 32bit pc and mobile also by simply launch it by clicking package and install it . It will take approx 30 sec to appear on list of apps. And alternately you can publish it on the store and store has facility - you can hide app from every one , only a person with link can   install your app. or use "Dev Share" app from store to do this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can package your UWP app as a Windows App Package (.appx or .appxbundle) file from VS. That package is also your installer! You can simply double-click to install it. Just make sure the package is singed with a certificate that is trusted on the target computer.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/packaging-uwp-apps